# Unknown function

Tags: php

I have a script called ranking.php. I call this script at the top of another script (headtohead.php) as follows:

```
include("ranking.php");
```

Within the ranking script, there is a function called 'win'. In the headtohead.php script, I have a function with the following:

```
global $form, $database, $foottour, $ranking;
```

And then within the function itself:

```
$newHomePoints = $ranking->win($homePoints, $homescore, $awayscore, ($homeStar - $awayStar));
```

I am getting the error saying that the function 'win' on the line where it's called is unknown?

Comment: Please always quote the *exact error message*

Comment: Is $ranking a class?  If it's not, then you should be able to just call `win($homePoints, $homescore, $awayscore, ($homeStar - $awayStar));` without mentioning ranking.

Comment: You need to provide the full wording of the error message, otherwise it's hard to tell. "Unknown function" does not mean much, only that it has not been defined.

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ranking->win(...)` is calling a method on an object.  Is the `win` function in `ranking.php` actually a method within a class?  If it's a standalone function then you have to call it as a standalone function.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to call the method only if exists:

```
if (method_exists('win', $ranking)) {
    $newHomePoints = $ranking->win($homePoints, $homescore, $awayscore, $homeStar - $awayStar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is $ranking an instance of class? if not you should use $ranking = new "name of class here"(); Can you post the source of ranking.php?